# Propiedades de Tomcat

Tags: java, genexus

Estimado es posible cambiar el nombre de carpeta del servlet y static

esto es en genexus 17 u6

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De poder cambiar, podes, el problema es que GX deja de copiar algunos archivos y los vas a tener que mantener a mano.

Answer (score 0):

las propiedades que están "deshabilitadas", se deben a que GeneXus infiere esos path en base al valor que tengas en la propiedad "Tomcat path". De esa manera arma las otras rutas para copiar todos los archivos necesarios para que tu aplicación ejecute en el Tomcat.

Te recomiendo que veas la documentación en el Wiki como forma de complementar mi respuesta: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet//wiki?48354,Tomcat+path+property

Saludos.